# why is default audio volume always at 100%

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio, video-streaming

It does not matter which website or which video player the website uses, whenever I open any webpage with a video the audio volume is always 100%. If i open a link with a video on yahoo or ESPN the audio volume is always 100%. I always wear headphones and it hurts my hearing if i forget to change the volume level before the video starts playing.  Can I change this in the browser settings (Firefox or Chrome) and is this some sort of HTML standard or preset value?

Answer (score 5):

Firefox
 ( NOTE: Works for HTML5 video)

1:Load about:config in the browser's address bar.
2:Confirm that you will be careful if this is the first time you open the configuration screen.
3:Search for the preference media.default_volume.
4:Double-click on the line and a prompt should appear.
5:It's default value is 1.0 which equates 100% volume.
6:Use it to change the value using the same system, e.g. 0.1 for 10%, or 0.6 for 60%.

Answer (score 0):

**For Chrome**

- Click the (3 dots) in the upper right.
- Click 'Settings'.
- Scroll down and select 'Site Settings'.
- Scroll down and select 'Sound'.
- Select 'Mute sites that play sound'. You will NEVER get scared by those ultra loud ads and news videos again.
- For sites that you DO want to hear audio (i.e. YouTube), just (right click) that sites tab, up at the top, and select 'Unmute Site'.

Chrome will remember the audio level you set when you leave.